# Can two nested threads be forked and joined in AngularJS $q without $q.defer()?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am forking off two series of steps, with two separate chunks of asynchronous actions per leg:

```
Time           Threads forking and joining:
 |                         *
 |                       /   \
 V                      /     \
                 +-----+       +-----+
                /                     \
               /                       \
        $http.get('/foo')         $http.get('/baz')
              |                         |
              V                         V
        $http.get('/bar')         $http.get('/blap') <-- Problem children
              |                         |
              V                         V
               \                       /
                \                     /
                 +------+     +------+
                         \   /
                          \ /
                           +
                           |
                  $log.log("Carry on")
```

Is it possible to do the above forking/joining without using `$q.defer()` in the the "problem child level"?

This is how I would do the above fork/join with `$q.defer()`

```
var left = $q.defer()
var right = $q.defer()
$http.get('/foo')
  .success(function() {
    $http.get('/bar')
      .success(function() {
        left.resolve()
      })
  })
$http.get('/baz')
  .success(function() {
    $http.get('/blap')
      .success(function() {
        right.resolve()
      })
  })

$q.all([left.promise,right.promise])
  .then(function() {
    $log.log("Carry on")
  })
```

Comment: What do you want the code to look like?

Comment: Is it possible to chain the promises without explicitly managing a `$q.defer()` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can return promises inside of the then functions to chain them

```
var promise1 = $http.get('/foo')
  .then(function() {
    return $http.get('/bar');
  })
var promise2 = $http.get('/baz')
  .then(function() {
    return $http.get('/blap');
  });

$q.all([promise1,promise2]).then(function(results){
    var promise1Result = results[0]; // result of /bar
    var promise2Result = results[1]; // result of /blap
    // .... and do stuff
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/k9h4v1vv/

Comment: Not by using the `.success()` function, no.

Comment: The `.success()` not working the same was the kicker.  Thanks.